# Hardcodes HashMap in Spring Controller

Tags: java

I am new to Spring development and is just exploring a bit.When I use a hardcoded HashMap in a controller it errors out

```
//all corresponding package imports
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    Map<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    contactMap.put("name", "John");
    contactMap.put("lastname", "Lennon");
    contactMap.put("genres", "Rock, Pop");
```

}

And when I put it under static block,it works fine

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

private static Map<String, String> contactMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    contactMap.put("name", "John");
    contactMap.put("lastname", "Lennon");
    contactMap.put("genres", "Rock, Pop");
}
```

}

What is the logic behind this?

Comment: It's basic Java syntax.  If executable code is just floating around in a Java class it's not clear when or what context it is supposed to execute in.  So it's not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not because of the Spring. You cant access instance method in a Java class if it is not inside a method or constructor.

Comment: Basic Java ...Did not think that way..Thanks!!